# Error in getting user attributes in amazon cognito

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services

I'm using aws cognito to manage users, I can correctly sign up and login but whenever I try to get the attributes of the user that just logged in, I get this error:
Local storage is missing an ID Token, Please authenticate

The flow is the following
1 - user logs in
2 - if the login is successful get the attributes

The user is correctly authenticated, but still it complains that is not, can someone help me?
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add your code as text instead of images, this makes it possible for others to find your question.